# Determining reason that chrome enterprise-deployed extension will not load

Tags: deployment, google-chrome-extension, local, enterprise

I have a locally sourced enterprise-installed extension which is installed via the ExtensionInstallForcelist policy.  The policy is visible on the chrome://policy page with a status of OK. The URL to the update manifest xml file is of the form "file:///c:/program%20files/xxx/updates.xml"  The .crx file is also located in the same folder "file:///c:/program%20files/xxx/myextension.crx"  I can successfully browse to both of those files.  Yet the extension does not load.

Is there any way to determine the reason that chrome is not loading the extension?  I do not see any indication of error. I have opened up the inspect developer window on the extension page, but see no console messages or exceptions.  Is there a log file I could look at, or some other means of determining why the extension is not loading?

UPDATE: Turned on logging and see the following:
[3752:3156:0327/171545:WARNING:extension_error_reporter.cc(79)] Extension error: Expected ID "kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe", but ID was "ijdpkgandgfnpbammiehlfpfpboclodn".
[3752:3440:0327/172253:WARNING:extension_protocols.cc(422)] Failed to GetPathForExtension: kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe
[3752:3440:0327/172253:WARNING:url_request_job_manager.cc(89)] Failed to map: chrome-extension://kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe/
[3752:3440:0327/172253:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(364)] OnResponseStarted: chrome-extension://kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe/
[3752:3440:0327/172253:VERBOSE1:resource_loader.cc(778)] ResponseCompleted: chrome-extension://kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe/
[3752:3156:0327/172253:VERBOSE1:navigator_impl.cc(298)] Failed Provisional Load: chrome-extension://kfegeekbdleinhdfillngiggbjiflghe/, error_code: -2, error_description: Unknown error., showing_repost_interstitial: 0, frame_id: 1

Comment: [How to enable logging](https://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging). See if it helps clarify the issue.

Comment: This had been working fine on Chrome 40, but no longer seems to work under Chrome 41. Have there been any changes from 40 to 41 which would affect this?

Is anyone else seeing this behavior?

Comment: Well then. ID mismatch - did you sign the extension with the same PEM file?

Comment: It turns out we had a mislabeled .crx file which we thought was one extension ID, but was really another.  Thanks for your help.